# Ubuntu touchpad issues

Tags: drivers, dell, touchpad, synaptics, xps

My touch pad is not scrolling when I try opening synaptiks I get the message "Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?", and in mouse and touch pad settings i do not get any touch pad option, I think the touch pad is being recognised as a generic mouse. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

```
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Then

```
synclient -l | grep TouchpadOff
```

if this outputs "1".

Change it to "0" by

```
synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

Comment: Hi there as stated in the question when I open synaptiks i get the message  "Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?"

Comment: Ah, sorry. Look at the edit

Comment: I managed to reinstall xserver-xorg-input-synaptics with the first two commands however when i try    synclient -l | grep TouchpadOff       I still get the message "Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?"

Comment: everything i try from other websites too all end up giving me this error "Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?" any ideas?

Comment: I found this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/linux/+bug/633225 seems to be the one that you got :\

Comment: This should give you a "mouse" at least

sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps

Comment: no change after typing in the last command you sent, cypress (the people who make the touchpad driver) have actually created a driver and released it and it is meant to be pre installed in ubuntu 13.04 onwards, i have 13.10, is there anyway i could reinstall that driver?